# Editing FormPreview form data before preview in Django

Tags: django, forms

I'd like to alter the data collected from the form after a user clicks Preview but before it is shown to them again.

```
class StoryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    story = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

class StoryFormPreview(FormPreview):

    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        # Do something with the cleaned_data, then redirect
        # to a "success" page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/form/success')
```

Before the preview is shown I want to append to whatever the user entered for the story field and add "Brought to you by so and so."  How would I go about that?  I've played around a lot with the process_preview and preview_post methods but couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can modify it with

```
def process_preview(self, request, form, context):
    """
    Given a validated form, performs any extra processing before displaying
    the preview page, and saves any extra data in context.
    """
    pass
```

UPD:

I found only solution with form clean method:

```
class StoryForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    def clean_story(self):
        self.cleaned_data['story'] = ...
        return self.cleaned_data['story']


class StoryFormPreview(FormPreview):

    def process_preview(self, request, form, context):
        preview_data = {}
        for key, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
            preview_data[key] = value

        context['preview_data'] = preview_data

formtools/preview.html

{% for label, data in preview_data.iteritems %}
<tr>
<th>{{ label }}:</th>
<td>{{ data }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned the process_preview method in the question.  I tried all sort of combinations of code and couldn't get it to work.  I need more...

Comment: I need to actually change what's being stored in the form.  As you have it, the appended information is only being displayed in the template.  It's not saved once they submit the form.

Comment: It should be saved. You can also rewrite preview_post method to use modified copy of request.POST to initialize the form.